# Combining two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried merging two dataframes, but I can't seem to get it to work. Each time I merge, the rows where I expect values are all 0. Dataframe `df1` already as some data in it, with some left blank. Dataframe `df2` will populate those blank rows in `df1` where column names match at each value in "TempBin" and each value in "Month" in `df1`.

EDIT:
Both dataframes are in a `for` loop. `df1` acts as my "storage", `df2` changes for each location iteration. So if `df2` contained the results for LocationZP, I would also want that data inserted in the matching `df1` rows. If I use `df1 = df1.append(df2)` in the `for` loop, all of the rows from `df2` keep inserting at the very end of `df1` for each iteration.

**df1:**

```
Month  TempBin  LocationAA   LocationXA   LocationZP
 1      0       7            1            2
 1      1       98           0            89
 1      2       12           23           38
 1      3       3            14           17
 1      4       7            9            14
 1      5       1            8            99
 13     0       0            0            0
 13     1       0            0            0
 13     2       0            0            0
 13     3       0            0            0
 13     4       0            0            0
 13     5       0            0            0
```

**df2:**

```
Month  TempBin  LocationAA
 13     0       11
 13     1       22
 13     2       33
 13     3       44
 13     4       55
 13     5       66
```

**desired output in df1:**

```
Month  TempBin  LocationAA   LocationXA   LocationZP
 1      0       7            1            2
 1      1       98           0            89
 1      2       12           23           38
 1      3       3            14           17
 1      4       7            9            14
 1      5       1            8            99
 13     0       11           0            0
 13     1       22           0            0
 13     2       33           0            0
 13     3       44           0            0
 13     4       55           0            0
 13     5       66           0            0
```

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [1]*6 + [13]*6,
                   'TempBin': [0,1,2,3,4,5]*2,
                   'LocationAA': [7,98,12,3,7,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'LocationXA': [1,0,23,14,9,8,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'LocationZP': [2,89,38,17,14,99,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
                   )

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [13]*6,
                   'TempBin': [0,1,2,3,4,5],
                   'LocationAA': [11,22,33,44,55,66]}
                   )

df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["Month","TempBin","LocationAA"], how="left")
```

**result:**

```
Month  TempBin  LocationAA  LocationXA  LocationZP
1      0        7.0         1.0         2.0
1      1        98.0        0.0         89.0
1      2        12.0        23.0        38.0
1      3        3.0         14.0        17.0
1      4        7.0         9.0         14.0
1      5        1.0         8.0         99.0
13     0        NaN         NaN         NaN
13     1        NaN         NaN         NaN
13     2        NaN         NaN         NaN
13     3        NaN         NaN         NaN
13     4        NaN         NaN         NaN
13     5        NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that worked for me:

```py
# Merge two df into one dataframe on the columns "TempBin" and "Month" filling nan values with 0.
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [1]*6 + [13]*6,
                   'TempBin': [0,1,2,3,4,5]*2,
                   'LocationAA': [7,98,12,3,7,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'LocationXA': [1,0,23,14,9,8,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'LocationZP': [2,89,38,17,14,99,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
                   )

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [13]*6,
                   'TempBin': [0,1,2,3,4,5],
                   'LocationAA': [11,22,33,44,55,66]})

df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', 
            left_on=['TempBin', 'Month'], 
            right_on=['TempBin', 'Month'])

df_merge.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# add column LocationAA and fill it with the not null value from column LocationAA_x and LocationAA_y
df_merge['LocationAA'] = df_merge.apply(lambda x: x['LocationAA_x'] if pd.isnull(x['LocationAA_y']) else x['LocationAA_y'], axis=1)

# remove column LocationAA_x and LocationAA_y
df_merge.drop(['LocationAA_x', 'LocationAA_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df_merge)
```

Output:

```
    Month  TempBin  LocationXA  LocationZP  LocationAA
0       1        0         1.0         2.0         0.0
1       1        1         0.0        89.0         0.0
2       1        2        23.0        38.0         0.0
3       1        3        14.0        17.0         0.0
4       1        4         9.0        14.0         0.0
5       1        5         8.0        99.0         0.0
6      13        0         0.0         0.0        11.0
7      13        1         0.0         0.0        22.0
8      13        2         0.0         0.0        33.0
9      13        3         0.0         0.0        44.0
10     13        4         0.0         0.0        55.0
11     13        5         0.0         0.0        66.0
```

Let me know if there's something you don't understand in the comments :)

PS: Sorry for the extra comments. But I left them there for some more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use append to get the desired output:

```
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

and if you want to replace the Nulls to zeros add:

```
df1 = df1.fillna(0)
```

Comment: That works for only appending once, but if I'm in a for loop appending multiple times, it will keep adding additional rows. I'll update my question to be more specific. Trying my best to convey as simple as I can.

Comment: Ok. because the posted DF2 does not have any unique column to contribute to DF1

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `combine_first()`

```
i = ['Month','TempBin']
df2.set_index(i).combine_first(df1.set_index(i)).reset_index()
```